# Pandas transform dataframe to get column names based on row condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing cars and the speed in a certain zone.

I want to transform the dataframe so I know which car had a speed bigger than 100 for every zone, so I obtain a row for every car and  two columns, differentiating the zones based on the 100 value.

Input:

| car id | speed_t1 | speed_t2 | speed_t3 | speed_t4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 90 | 80 | 120 | 34 |
| 2. | 110 | 130 | 140 | 99 |
| 3. | 40 | 110 | 20 | 110 |

Expected output:

| car id | normal_speed_t | high_speed_t |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | speed_t1,speed_t2,speed_t4 | speed_t3 |
| 2. | speed_t4 | speed_t1,speed_t2,speed_t3 |
| 3. | speed_t1,speed_t3 | speed_t2,speed_t4 |

Comment: Is the third ID on the expected output a typo? should it be 3 or could there be actual duplicated IDs in the output?

Comment: @NicolòGasparini You are right it was a typo, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `DataFrame.apply` on `axis=1`, then join the columns by `,` which has the value less than or greater than the given value.

```py
df.assign(normal_speed_t=df.apply(lambda x:','.join(x[x<100].index), axis=1),
          high_speed_t=df.apply(lambda x:','.join(x[x>=100].index), axis=1)
          )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
        speed_t1  speed_t2  speed_t3  speed_t4              normal_speed_t                high_speed_t
car id                                                                                                 
1.0           90        80       120        34  speed_t1,speed_t2,speed_t4                    speed_t3 
2.0          110       130       140        99                    speed_t4  speed_t1,speed_t2,speed_t3 
3.0           40       110        20       110           speed_t1,speed_t3           speed_t2,speed_t4
```

Break-Down:

- `assign` just lets you assign a new column with given values
- `.apply` allows you to apply some function to the dataframes columnwise for `axis=0`, and row-wise for `axis=1`
- `x[x<100].index` will filter the values that are less than 100, and get the index i.e. column index/column names
- `','.join(....)` it is joining the columns that are coming from above step

Comment: can you. please explain your solution parts by parts?

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire, Please look at the updated answer

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for non iterative solution with columns names with separator, so is necessary remove last value `,` by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df.assign(normal_speed_t=(df<100).dot(df.columns + ',').str.strip(','),
          high_speed_t=(df>=100).dot(df.columns + ',').str.strip(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

`apply` isn't the most efficient solution but I couldn't think of a better one.
Also the conditions are based on the column name (containing 'speed') to avoid considering additional columns such as the car_id

```
df["normal"] = df.apply(lambda row: ",".join([x for x in df.columns if "speed" in x and row[x]<=100]), axis=1)
df["high"] = df.apply(lambda row: ",".join([x for x in df.columns if "speed" in x and row[x]>100]), axis=1)
```